# My website page shrinks and I think issue in CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Please suggest me or edit this code. I am searching and trying to fix the problem. My page shrinks when I maximize or restore it. Please look at my CSS code. I am not allowed to use any framework like bootstrap. I am pasting my fiddle code here. If possible please correct it.

CSS code is

```
#container {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    display:block;
}


.container-1 input#search{
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    background:gray;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12pt;
    float: right;
    display:block;
    padding-right: 100%;


}


.form-wrapper {

    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top:10%;
    right: 50px;
    background:grey;

}

#image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#text {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 45em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size:25px;
    left: 150px;
    top: 600px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

#about {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:44px;
    left: 550px;
    top: 520px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}


#con {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size:44px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 250px;
    top: 550px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}


#project {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-size:44px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 500px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

#projectp {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 300px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 600px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

#projectpc {
    width: 40em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
#p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-style: italic;


}

#pr{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:40px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-width: medium;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 500px;


}

div.img {
    margin: 65px;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}


div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-weight: bold;
}




#contact {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:44px;
    left: 570px;
    top: 480px;
}

#contact1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size:30px;
    left: 520px;
    top: 560px;
}


h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:44px ;
    display:block;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:30px;
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#left {
    color: rgba(16, 9, 18, 0.57);
    position: absolute;
    top: 1500px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 23em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;

}


p.ex {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    display:block;
}

h3{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}


h4{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    font-size:20px;
}





#img_cont a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: 26%;
}


#imagepr {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
#image1 {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 520px;
    height:40px;
}

#image2 {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:52px;
    height:40px;
}

#image3 {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:52px;
    height:40px;

}
#image4 {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:52px;
    height:40px;

}

h3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 800px;
    top: 1880px;
    display:block;
}


.heading{float:right;
    width: 16em;
    word-wrap: break-word;}

.heading1{float:right;
    width: 22em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-top: -200px;

}

#image24 {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:72px;


}
 h2.pos_left {
     color: rgba(16, 9, 18, 0.57);
     position: absolute;
     top: 1450px;
    margin-left: 100px;

 }




  h2.pos_right {
      word-wrap: break-word;
      color:rgba(16, 9, 18, 0.57);
      position: absolute;
      left: 670px;
      top: 1450px;
      display:block;
      margin-left:150px;
  }
#right {
    color: rgba(16, 9, 18, 0.57);
    position: absolute;
    top: 1530px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 23em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:680px;

}


footer {
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;


}  footer a {
       color: #100912;
       text-decoration: none;
   }


#footer ul {
    text-align: center;




}
#footer li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #18210b;



}
```

HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DROPS and Crops</title>



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsiveslides.css">
    <script src="js/jquery183.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
          // Slideshow
          $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
            auto: true,
            pager: false,
            nav: true,
            speed: 500,
            namespace: "callbacks",
            before: function () {
              $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
            },
            after: function () {
              $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
            }
          });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap-body">

<!--////////////////////////////////////Header-->
<header>
    <div class="">
        <div class="wrap-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-3">
                    <div class="wrap-col">
                        <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/drops.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
                <div class="col-1-3 offset-1-3">
                    <div class="wrap-col">
                        <form class="form-wrapper cf" >
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>


                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div>
            <nav id="menu-wrap"><div id="menu-trigger">Menu</div>
            <ul id="menu" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">About</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="single.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="single.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
</body>


        <div class="slider">

            <div class="callbacks_container">
                <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
                    <li>
                        <div style="text-align: center"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="image"/></div>

                        <p id="text">
                            In 2050, we are projected to have 9 billion on this planet. These people will eat and drink just like we do..
                        requiring a doubling of food production. But food and water security already are the largest challenges for a

                                           thriving global population.





                            Drops and Crops is a network of students, researchers, social innovators and entrepreneurs trying to tackle this
                             great challenge of our lifetimes through partnerships and collaborations. Our network is supported by the Water


                                                   for Food Institute at the University of Nebraska.
                        </p>


                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>





        <h1>LEARN MORE</h1>

<h2>about our current<a href="single.html"> Projects</a> </h2>


    <!--////////////////////////////////////Project Section-->

<div id="header">
    <img id="imag23" src="images/banner-img1.jpg"alt="img"  >
    <img id="imag24" src="images/banner-img2.jpg"alt="img" >

</div>

<div>
    <h2 class="pos_left"> SYRIAN CRISIS </h2>
    <p id="left"> We are organizing a conference in April 2016 on
     water and humanitarian aspects of the Syrian crisis.
     Click <a href="projectc.html">here</a> to learn about the crisis and our
     conference.</p>
    </div>

<div>
<h2 class="pos_right">SMALLHOLDER </br> AGRICULTURE</h2>
<p id="right">We are organizing a workshop in April 2016 on smallholder irrigation in Sub-Saharan Africa. Click here
 to learn about the challenge of agriculture in the
region and our workshop.</p>
    </div>
<div>

<h1> Latest From Our <a href="single.html">Blog</a></h1>
</div>

<div>
    <!--////////////////////////////////////Footer-->


    <img src="images/2.jpg" class="myImage" alt="images/2"/>
    <h2 class="heading">HOW MUCH DO YOU KNOW ABOUT THE WORLD'S BIGGEST  HUMANITARIAN CRISIS?  </h2>


    <h4 class="heading1">Click here to see our more recent infographic on humanitarian aspects of the Syrian crisis </h4>





    </div>





<!--////////////////////////////////////Social Media-->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Drops-and-Crops-705675629533002/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img id="image1" src="http://waterforfood.nebraska.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/facebook.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/drops_and_crops" target="_blank"><img id="image2" src="http://waterforfood.nebraska.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/twitter.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/DropsandCrops/" target="_blank"><img id="image3" src="http://waterforfood.nebraska.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/pinterest.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/water-for-food-institute-at-university-of-nebraska" target="_blank"><img id="image4" src="http://waterforfood.nebraska.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/linkedin.png" alt="image"></a>

<!--   Footer          -->




<footer>
    <div id="footer">

        <ul class="footer" id="footersection">
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US | </a></li>

            <li><a href="#">CREDITS | </a></li>

            <li><a href="#">waterforfood.nebraska.edu  </a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>

</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bsp27L9s/3/

Comment: In three words: avoid absolute positioning.

Comment: everywhere in the whole coding?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need it, yes

Comment: @hell123 When you absolute position elements, it's like you printed them out from an entirely different page and just pasted them on top (like a Post-it Note in a textbook). They entirely stop affecting the layout of the page, and they can cause all sorts of frustrating placement issues for you.

Comment: @j08691 First the problem is in search bar, it changes it position from right to left. I removed position absolute. It changes it position from right to bottom of the header. But if I use position it shrinks.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "My page shrinks when I maximize or restore it"? I'm using Chrome, and I don't see the page shrinking in any way that it shouldn't. Sorry if I'm missing the problem.

Comment: @Nate well thanks for reply, I am also using chrome, its elements gets away from its original position when I change the size of browser screen.

Answer (score -1):

@j08691 he is right! use a grid sistem maybe bootstrap? or susy, or well there is so much out there, and if you are in learning mode I recommend you start with youtube about css tutorials and best practices